# gcc __rdtscp documentation

Tags: gcc, intrinsics, built-in

I see the following in gcc's ia32intrin.h:

```
/* rdtscp */
extern __inline unsigned long long
__attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
__rdtscp (unsigned int *__A)
{
  return __builtin_ia32_rdtscp (__A);
}
```

But I cannot find any other documentation for __builtin_ia32_rtdtscp (and what to pass in for __A in particular)

Are these builtin's not meant to be used or are they just not documented?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385235(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to look at an asm instruction set manual, like Intel's (links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).

`rdtscp` produces a 64bit timestamp result (which is obviously the return value), and a 32bit `IA32_TSC_AUX`.

From the way the instruction works, we can also conclude that the initial value pointed to by `__A` doesn't matter: it's just a pointer to write-only storage for the result.